# Discord BOT with Python, How to make it reply in the channel we send the command (Done)

Tags: python, discord, bots, message

> ***Done! Thanks to anyone who helped me out:) Still maybe you have better answers, so, feel free to answer!***

I know, this may look like a stupid question, but if you consider that I'm a beginner in **making bots for Discord** in Python beyond all my other Python knowledge and Stack Overflow being probably a place just for that, I hope it wouldn't. (I'm so new that I literally woke everyone in the home up by my happiness when I saw my bot turned online lol)

**As I saw in other posts, tutorial, etc.; (don't mind the usage of , and ; it could be wrong) we have to specify the ID of the channel, so how can we just reply in the channel the user has sent the command in? Maybe getting the ID of the current channel with some type of a command? I don't know.**

```
import discord

TOKEN = 'XXXXX'

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
        msg = 'Hi {0.author.mention}'.format(message)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

(Since I'm lazy regenerating tokens, i made it xxxxx in this example but don't worry i put it in the normal code.)

As I saw, there is no same question even though there are similar ones (i couldnt see an answer or a question definitely because everybody knows how to do that)

The problem is in the send_message part. It gives an error.

Comment: yes I got the first mention thanks.  doesn't `message.channel` get the channel id from the message's channel?  I don't think I understand what you are looking for?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen But it gives an error saying that send_message is not a valid command for Client.

(Edit: sorry for asking the actual question in a wrong way, i tried the answers from many other stack overflow posts which i used and if didn't work just deleted. 
So i probably got another error from one of them and the one i was 
talking about, was that one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to get the channel object and send a message to it using `message.channel.send()` and not `client.send_message()`

```
if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
    msg = 'Hi {0.author.mention}'.format(message)
    await message.channel.send(msg)
```

In the future you may wanna try something like this or maybe come across it by any reason:

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command()
#This is defining a '!hello' command
async def hello(ctx):
    #In this case you have to use the ctx to send the message
    #Good to remember that ctx is NOT a parameter wich the user will give
    msg = f'Hi {ctx.author.mention}'
    await ctx.send(msg)
```

Comment: Thanks @Voz! Ihave already fixed it but it still helped!

Comment: You are welcome :). I would apreciate a lot if you pick mine as best answer.

Comment: Ummm  I have never done that before... With the check icon..?

Comment: Yes, with the check icon https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers check this link if you got any doubts on how to do so

Comment: Just did it @Voz! :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can send messages. One is using the on_message but I would recommend against it because it might interfere with other commands in your code.

Example:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client(command_prefix='!')

@client.event
async def on_ready()
 print('Bot is ready')

#example message
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
 await ctx.send('This message is a test')

client.run('YOUR TOKEN')
```

You can call the test command by doing "!test" in the bot channel.

Answer (score -1):

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='Your Prefered Prefix')

@client.command()
async def hi(ctx):
  channel = ctx.message.channel
  await channel.send(f"hi {ctx.author.name}!")


client.run(Token)
```